# Installing Linux on UEFI ASUS Machine

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I have been having troubles for weeks trying to get Linux Mint on my new computer. It is a ASUS F75V-NS1 with UEFI Bios and Windows 8 install. So far, I was able to get a Linux Mint 64-bit Bootable ISO from USB installed on a partition of my HD. However, when I installed, my wireless was not working. `rfkill list all` would always show my phy0 having a physical block on it. So I thought maybe it was because it was 64-bit and not 32-bit. But when I went to install 32-bit ISO on my USB it says the ISO is not UEFI compatible even tho it is exactly like the 64-bit version. So does UEFI only work with 64-bit images? If so then I don't know what else to try. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [release notes](http://linuxmint.com/rel_olivia.php) for Linux Mint 15 (I assume that's what you're using, you did not say) state:

> The 32-bit ISOs of Linux Mint 15 use a PAE kernel. If your processor is not compatible with PAE please use Linux Mint 13 Maya LTS instead. Linux Mint 13 is supported until 2017.

So, I don't think that a 64bit processor will be compatible with [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) since that is a feature designed to allow 32bit processors to access more than 4 gigabytes of memory. If so, then it is likely that you can't install the 32bit version on your machine.

It is also exceedingly likely that you don't want to. Keep the 64bit version and post a new question explaining your wireless issues and we should be able to help you solve that.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I have had problems with wireless for a while and never find a solution

Comment: @MattHintzke a great resource for that is [Linux Wireless](http://wireless.kernel.org/). I find it very unlikely that your wireless can't be fixed, worse case scenario, you'll have to use the windows driver and [ndiswrapper](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page). Post a question and include your wireless device and we should be able to help you.